# Tensorflow. One column array (200,) into one column placeholder [None, 1] gives shape error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have a dataset with label that is a vector with 200 rows, 1 column, so (200,) shape for array. I create my placeholder like this to make it dynamic and ready to take my array

```
y_placeh = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, [None, 1])
```

When I try to insert my data into the placeholder I get this error:

```
 ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (200,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_79:0', 
 which has shape '(?, 1)'
```

I thought those two shapes were the same? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shape `(x, 1)` is a two dimensional tensor (matrix), which has one column. Shape `(x, )` is one dimensional tensor (vector).

So make either both things a vector or a matrix.

Comment: Aha! Thanks! I thought a two dimensional tensor with one column was a vector. Anyways I will give it a try